# How to deal with subsetting in SAS

Tags: merge, dataset, sas, analytics, subset

I am very new to SAS and I am very eager to learn it. My question is about subsetting. I have 2 data sets; a and b namely consisting og two columns a and b respectively:

```
a      b
3      4
       5
       6 

  data a;
  set a;
  run;
  data b;
  set b;
  run;
  data merged;
  merge a b;
  run;
  proc print data=merged(firstobs= a[1] obs=a[1] keep= b);
  run;
```

In this code I get invalid conversion type error and I could not figure out why I am getting this error because when I write like:

```
  proc print data=merged(firstobs= 3 obs= 3 keep= b);
  run;
```

I get the result as 6.

I know it seems very simple but I am stuck with this error. If you help me I would really appreciate. Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do with the first `proc print`?

Comment: @user667489 I am trying to build a dependency so that for example when column a is changed from 3 to 2 then my result should also be changed.

Comment: Your code doesn't really make sense - why are you merging them side-by-side?

Answer (score 0):

You want to print the row from the dataset `b` whose number is the same as the value of `a` in row 1 of the dataset `a`.

You can't pass a value into a proc directly like that, but you can generate a macro variable from your dataset and pass it into the proc, e.g.

```
data _null_;
  set a(obs = 1);
  call symput('ROW_NUMBER',a);
run;

proc print data = b(keep = b obs = &ROW_NUMBER firstobs = &ROW_NUMBER);
run;
```